# node-outlook doesn't let me grant permissions to a different email

Tags: javascript, azure, email, outlook-restapi

So I built a simple app, and I'm trying to integrate Outlook's API into it. I made an outlook account, registered an app and set everything with the keys. When it takes me to the Azure login page I log int with the account I registered the app with, and I'm able to return JSON data of the account's calendar.

However, when I try another outlook account I get an issue:

`getUserEmail returned an error: [object Object]`

This is the following function:

```
// Function to retrieve email in order to find user
async function getUserEmail(token) {
  // Create a Graph client
  const client = microsoftGraph.Client.init({
    authProvider: done => {
      // First parameter is is error handling if no token is retrieved
      // If token is available then return the token
      done(null, token);
    }
  });

  const res = await client.api('/me').get();

  // Outlook.com users have userPrincipalName instead of a mail attribute
  return res.mail ? res.mail : res.userPrincipalName;
}
```

Consoling the error itself returns this message:

`all the offeractions provided in the property bag cannot be validated for the token`

I'm really confused now, why can I only access the data with the account I registered the app with? Do I have to change something else in the app registration?

Comment: Make sure you've provided the proper permission scopes during the login.

Answer (score 0):

Is the other user from your own organization? If not, The IT administrator of the company with xyz domain (email@xyz.onmicrosoft.com) has to give consent on behalf of the whole company so that the users of that company will be able to use your application. Here is a very good example of the flow:

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/implementing-admin-consent-multitenant-office-365-applications-implicit-oauth-flow/